# Crashlytics missing symbols on some crashes

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

On my Android app, sometimes, some crashes have missing symbols. Most of the crashes show the complete symbolicated callstack.

Example:

```html
# Platform: android
# Application: World Soccer Challenge


#0. Crashed: Thread
0  (Missing)                      0xde097340 (Missing)
1  (Missing)                      0x3a8bf734 (Missing)
2  (Missing)                      0xde096cd5 (Missing)
3  (Missing)                      0x3a8bf734 (Missing)
4  (Missing)                      0xde0978f7 (Missing)
5  (Missing)                      0xde09657d (Missing)
6  (Missing)                      0x3a8bf734 (Missing)
7  (Missing)                      0x3a8bf734 (Missing)
8  (Missing)                      0xde0aa457 (Missing)
9  (Missing)                      0xde088321 (Missing)
10 (Missing)                      0x3a8bf734 (Missing)
11 (Missing)                      0x3a8bf734 (Missing)
12 (Missing)                      0xde089697 (Missing)
13 (Missing)                      0xde1282be (Missing)
14 (Missing)                      0xde08ef21 (Missing)
.....
```

What can I do?
I'm using com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.2

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Are you using NDK and if so, uploading symbols for each build?

Comment: I am. And I see symbolicated callstacks for every other issue, just not for this one.

Comment: after generating the signed apk, I do a: gradlew crashlyticsUploadSymbolsRelease to upload the symbols

Comment: Since we're chatting over email as well, let's finish the conversation there and then we can post an answer here for the rest of the folks.

Comment: please post your solution here.